Power Query Expand Table Column to Access Attachment Contents
I have an Excel Workbook that is stored in a Dataverse column as an attachment. I would like to access the data in this file in Power Query using the Table.ExpandTableColumn. How can this be achieved?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/dataverse
